# Installing dependencies and compiling a C# hello world project

Tags: java, c#, maven

I have a very simple [hello world repo](https://github.com/cloudfoundry-samples/dotnet-core-hello-world) written in C# with a .csproj file with its dependencies. I'm very very new to C#, what I'm trying to do is install the dependencies and compile the project.

In a Java project I can achieve this by running `mvn clean install-f filePath` in the command line.

How can I achieve the same in C#.

Ive already look for anwers in here and done some research but since I'm very new to C# alot does not make sence to me.

Comment: Are you using Visual Studio?

Comment: Either use Visual Studio, or the `dotnet` command line tools.

Comment: When you open the project in Visual Studio, it will restore the packages automatically. Likewise, if you build the project from the command line using the `dotnet build` command, it will restore any missing packages. If you want to just restore packages, without building, you can run `dotnet restore`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ensure that you are having dotnet sdk installed (For your repository, it is .NET Core SDK 2.1). Just use

```
dotnet build dotnet-core-hello-world.csproj
```

for your sample repository. It will restore the dependencies as well as build the project. It will put runnable dll in bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.1 folder. Then just use in this folder

```
dotnet dotnet-core-hello-world.dll
```

and it will run your application